# CURLCLOSEPOLICY_LEAST_RECENTLY_USED not defined anymore in PHP 5.6.4: is it better to replace with something else or to comment out the reference?

Tags: php, wordpress, curl

I've just moved my PHP application (WooCommerce above Wordpress) to a server using PHP 5.6.4 and I get this warning:

```
Warning: curl_setopt() expects parameter 2 to be long, string given in /srv/users/serverpilot/apps/wordpress/public/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce-amazon-s3-storage/amazon_sdk/lib/requestcore/requestcore.class.php on line 610
```

As far as I can see, it happens when I'm trying to reference to this built-in var `CURLCLOSEPOLICY_LEAST_RECENTLY_USED` which is not defined anymore on PHP 5.6

Is it better to replace with `CURLCLOSEPOLICY_OLDEST` or to comment out the `curl_setopt($handle,       CURLOPT_CLOSEPOLICY, CURLCLOSEPOLICY_LEAST_RECENTLY_USED)` set?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **CURLOPT_CLOSEPOLICY One of the CURLCLOSEPOLICY_*** values. Note: This
>   option is deprecated, as **it was never implemented** in cURL and never
>   had any effect.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php

Just remove this line

Comment: tnx allot for speed and clarity :)